# LG volt stuck in powering on phase

Tags: lg-volt

I restarted my LG volt and now it's stuck on the phase where it's powering on and won't actually move on to the home menu. How can i fix this?

Comment: Where is it exactly stuck? On the OEM's logo or on boot animation or on something else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the phrasing of the question, I'm going to assume that the phone is running completely original software, and that you have not rooted or flashed custom ROMs.

Try clearing dalvik cache on the phone by following these steps:

1. With the phone off, hold down the Volume Down button and Power button at the same time for 5 seconds
2. There should now be a very basic menu with a picture of Andy the Android centered on the screen.
3. In the menu, there will be items listed along the lines of `Reboot, Install .zip, Wipe data, Clear Cache, etc` If you don't see this, try the button combination again.
4. Use the Volume down key to highlight the `Clear Cache` or `Wipe Cache` or `Clear Dalvik Cache` option
5. Hit the power button to confirm your selection. This will bring up another menu with `Are you sure? NO NO YES NO` You will have to select `YES`.
6. Reboot the device

If this doesn't solve it let me know

Comment: didnt work phone is still on a booting lg screen and it dosnt have the up and down with the volume it has tabs to push with ur finger im getting no where